# Make an int vector receive the values from a vector of a class that has an int

Tags: c++

So, suppose I have this:

```
...
struct circle {
   int radius;
   char color;   
}    

vector<circle> circles; 
...

vector<int> sizes;    
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
    sizes[i] = circles[i].radius;
}
...
```

is there a way of making "sizes" receive automatically all "radius" without the "for" routine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: It's fairly clear in modern C++: `for (auto const & c : circles) sizes.push_back(c.radius);`

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer if it helped. Click the checkmark under the score marker to accept an answer. If you're still having trouble with your program in relation to this question, leave a comment below the answer that you went with explaining what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(
    std::begin(circles), std::end(circles), std::back_inserter(sizes),
    [](const circle &c) {return c.radius;}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have a "slice" of a vector content.

There are algorithms that could create the result so the for loop is not in the open, but it still happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for_each` if you want another alternative to chris' transform. The following example does not use lambda expressions (C++11) unlike chris' example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct{
  int radius;
  char color;   
} circle;

std::vector<int> *intvecPtr=NULL;

struct myclass {
  void operator() (circle x)
     {
      if (intvecPtr != NULL) 
            intvecPtr->push_back(x.radius);
     }
  } myobject;


int main(void)
{

   circle x;

   std::vector<circle> circles; 
   for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
     {
         x.radius = 2*(i+1);
         x.color = (i+1);
         circles.push_back(x);
     }

   std::vector<int> sizes;
   sizes.reserve(circles.size());
   intvecPtr = &sizes;
   std::for_each(circles.begin(), circles.end(), myobject);

   for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
       printf("%d,",sizes[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

}
```